Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' When upgrade the app to Spring boot 3.3.0
I started getting this exception below in my integration test when I upgraded my spring boot version to 3.3.0. I'm not sure why Hibernate is trying to use Javax/xml annotation. Even though I added Jakarta dependencies to my pom file and with the new Spring boot version, it's suppose to use Jakarta annotations not Javax. Any idea how to make Hibernate Auto Configuration uses Jakarta instead of Javax?
Error:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
 name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: 
javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement

Pom.xml:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>com.example.demo</artifactId>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-types-55</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.transaction-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.224</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.73.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
        <version>7.73.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-internal</artifactId>
        <version>7.73.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


Your dependency on com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-55 is pulling in Hibernate 5.x. You should replace the dependency with one on com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-60. 2.21.1 is the latest version at the time of writing.
